# UITableViewController unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableviewcontroller and a detailtableviewcontroller when I pass an integer I get

**-[UITableViewController setSurveyNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Bizard thing is exact same code works for tableviewcontroller to -> uiviewcontroller

table -> table code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushSurveyDetails"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

        SurveyDetailViewController *surveyController = [segue destinationViewController];
        surveyController.surveyNumber=row;

    }
}
```

in SurveyDetailViewController.h

```
@interface SurveyDetailViewController : UITableViewController
{

}

@property int surveyNumber;

@end
```

SurveyDetailViewController.m

```
@implementation SurveyDetailViewController
@synthesize surveyNumber;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Survey Number is %i",surveyNumber);
}
```

why this error occurs?

Comment: Is surveydetails.h the same one you are assuming it is when you creating SurveyDetailViewController, because it should be SurveyDetailViewController.h and .m

Comment: it is just typo SurveyDetailViewController is surveydetails let me edit question

Comment: The error message indicates that `[segue destinationViewController]` returns a `UITableViewController` and not a `SurveyDetailViewController`. Perhaps you forgot to set the class of the controller in the storyboard file?

Comment: @MartinR you are right, I tried few times to enter class name on IB but it did not show up automatically so I have must forgotten that. I tried again and now it works,  Please provide answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message indicates that `[segue destinationViewController]` returns a `UITableViewController` and not a `SurveyDetailViewController` as expected.

The controller class can be set in the storyboard file.

Comment: Future reader, FYI, the same error may occur if you have mistakenly put the same identifier on multiple segues in the storyboard.