# Swift: Unable to segue from a UIViewController to a UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to pass data from a `UIViewController` class to another view, a `UITableViewController`. I can successfully pass data from `UIViewController` to `UIViewController` via:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueName") {
            var target = segue!.destinationViewController as NextViewController
            target.name = self.nameText.text
        }
}
```

But trying to use this logic to go from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` gives me 
"`Swift dynamic cast failed`" at the point of the "`var target...`" line. I get no build errors and Xcode knows there is a variable "name" in the next view controller (the `UITableViewController`) waiting for data to be assigned to it.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the custom class of the destination table view controller in the storyboard is set to "NextViewController"?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that isn't the problem. (Thanks for responding.)

Comment: Does this comment from @DelightedD0D help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263644/uitableviewcontroller-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance#comment36524555_14264088 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just to test things, I removed the 'prepareForSegue' method from the first view controller class, and modified the code in the 'UITableViewController' class, and still get a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure there are no side-effects, because your function signature looks somewhat strange regarding the optionals. Try this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueName") {
        if let target = segue.destinationViewController as? NextViewController
            target.name = self.nameText.text
        }
    }
}
```

Then place a breakpoint in that function and step through the code to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me realize the data are indeed moved successfully, so now I expect there is something wrong with the UITableView Controller and what kind of data it is expecting to break down and display. I'm passing an NSArray of NSDictionaries via segue, and I want to display the value of one of the keys for each of these dictionaries (same key for each dictionary).

Comment: It's working.I had the wrong key for the value I wanted to display in the Table